# Refile gem : multiple file uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, file, refile

I'm using Refile with Rails 4. I'm following their tutorial for [multiple image upload](https://github.com/refile/refile#multiple-file-uploads). Each Post can have multiple Images. My models look like this:

Post.rb:

```
has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
accepts_attachments_for :images, attachment: :file
```

Image.rb:

```
belongs_to :post
attachment :file
```

I can upload files, fine by using:

```
<%= f.attachment_field :images_files, multiple: true, direct: true, presigned: true %>
```

but when I try to retrieve an image like:

```
 <%= attachment_image_tag(@post.images, :file, :small) %>
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method file for #<Image::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbaf51e8ea0>
```

How can I retrieve an image with refile using multiple image upload?

Comment: Here is the source for attachment_image_tag: https://github.com/refile/refile/blob/master/lib/refile/rails/attachment_helper.rb#L39

Comment: I also forgot to mention that if I do `@post.images.inspect`, I get an association with each object having the file nil, and the file_id set to the presigned, so I think that's part working fine. It's just when I try to view the image that it errors.

Comment: What is `@post` ? Is it a ***single record*** or a ***collection of records*** ? Please post the code for `@post`.

Comment: @Pavan, @post is a single record. I did @post.inspect on show.html.erb and got: `#<Post id: 2, name: "RefileTest", created_at: "2015-07-04 23:54:00", updated_at: "2015-07-04 23:54:00"`

Answer (score 5):

In order to retrieve images who *belongs to* a post, you need to iterate through the *array of images*.

```
<% @post.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= attachment_image_tag(image, :file, :fill, 300, 300) %>
<% end %>
```

The helper `attachment_image_tag` take:

- [Refile::Attachment] object : Instance of a class **which has an attached file**.
- [Symbol] name : The name of the attachment column

So here, `@posts.images` holds an array of `image` object. It's that object who has an attached file.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attachment :file
end
```

Then when you iterate `images`, you give to the helper the `image object`, and the name of the attachment column, here `:file`.

Comment: @Frorent Ferry, this doesn't work, I get the error: undefined method `file' for #<Image::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f8d1adb7b90>

Comment: Have you a ´file_id:string´ on your Image migration ? Have you run ´rake db:migrate ´ ?

Comment: @Frorent Ferry, Yes, I have a file_id:string for my Image model. It shows in my schema file, so it definitely has been migrated.

Comment: So it works for me. Have you set `images_files` in strong params ? `params.require(:post).permit(..., images_files: [])` If yes, I can share my  repo app used to write my response.

Comment: @frorent Ferry, I do have that in controller already. I would love to see the repo if you get a chance, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the master branch?

```
gem 'refile', require: "refile/rails", git: 'https://github.com/refile/refile.git', branch: 'master'
```

Comment: This should be comment